# Why I use `CoolTerm` connect to the switch's console port, there get messy code when I type the keyboard?

Tags: macos, switch

Why I use `CoolTerm` connect to the switch's console port, there get messy code when I type the keyboard.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

this is the options of `CoolTerm`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

my switch is Juniper EX4300, my OS is macOS sierra 10.12.6.

---

**EDIT-01**

I also tried use the mac Terminal:

```
screen /dev/tty.whcusbserial1410 9600
```

still this error.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart There is no putty for mac.

Comment: I did see the macos tag and screenshots, is there another terminal emulator you can try? These also have mini-usb as a com option right? Make sure that your roll-over cable is ok if you are connecting to the rj45 style serial port. You have the connection settings correct, so I'm guessing something physical is to blame.